# How to override a method and still be able to use the base method in the overridden one

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
function test(){};

test.prototype.testMethod = function(){return 1;}

var t = new test();
t.testMethod();
```

now I need to override the method testMethod so that I can still call the base method in the override.
How can I do that using prototype ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to overwrite the base method for an individual instance, you can still refer to the one defined in the prototype:

```
function test(){};

test.prototype.testMethod = function() {console.log('testMethod in prototype');}

var t = new test();
t.testMethod = function () {
    console.log(this);
    console.log('testMethod override');
    test.prototype.testMethod();    
};
t.testMethod();
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/aeBWS/

If you want to replace the prototype method itself, you have a couple of routes. The most simple one is to just chose a different name for your function. If that isn't possible, then you could copy the old method to one with a new name (like `_testMethod`) and call it that way:

```
function test(){};

test.prototype.testMethod = function() {console.log('testMethod in prototype');}  

test.prototype._oldTestMethod = test.prototype.testMethod;

test.prototype.testMethod = function() {
    console.log('testMethod override');
    test.prototype._oldTestMethod ();    
};

var t = new test();
t.testMethod();
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/x4txH/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reference of the old method on the test prototype like so:

```
function test(){};

test.prototype.testMethod = function(){
  return 1;
}

function test2(){};

test2.prototype = new test();

test2.prototype.testMethod = function(){
  return test.prototype.testMethod()
};
```